# How to query the inverse side of a ManyToOne relationship?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Long story short: each `Organization` can relate to (can have) many `User` objects and each `User` relates to (has) one `Organization`.

Each User can belong to a single Organization and each Organization can have many users. So it's textbook ManyToOne.

So far so good. I setup my classes as follows (I'll leave out the irrelevant parts):

**User class**:

```
// User.php
/** @ORM\Entity */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Organization::class, inversedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="organization_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $organization;


    public function getOrganization(): ?Organization
    {
        return $this->organization;
    }

    public function setOrganization(?Organization $organization): self
    {
        $this->organization = $organization;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Organization class**:

```
/** @ORM\Entity */
class Organization
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=User::class, mappedBy="organization")
     */
    private $user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|User[]
     */
    public function getUser(): Collection
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

}
```

In the organization repo I've setup a simple query using doctrine to fetch all the organizations that a user belongs to(which should be a max of 1):

```
class OrganizationRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    private $security;

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry, Security $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
        parent::__construct($registry, Organization::class);
    }

    public function selectAllFromUser()
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
            ->andWhere('o.user = :user')
            // ->where('o.user = :user') tried with this too
            ->setParameter('user', $this->security->getUser())
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
            ;
    }
```

Which gives me the following error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 48 near 'user = :user': Error: Invalid
> PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or
> SingleValuedAssociationField expected.

Admittedly there is no FK on organization so it's normal from a SQL point of view to issue an error. But on paper this is the relationship I want.

So what I am doing wrong here?

I could also use [One-To-Many, Unidirectional with Join Table](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table) but at that point it's easier to use ManyToMany and enforce the ManyToOne by code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you are overcomplicating things.

You do not need to go through the repository at all, or create a query builder.

If you want to get the organization from a user, just use your domain and get the organization.

```
$organization = $user->getOrganization();

if (!$organization instanceof Organization) {
    // it appears this user was organizationless, which I would assume
    // is an error condition for your application, but since you typed
    // $organiza as nullable, it's possible and should be checked against 
}
```

There, you are done. Wherever you were going to inject your `OrganizationRepository`, just inject `Security` or whatever method/service you use to get the user, and get its organization directly.

---

Second, you have a naming problem. The property `user` should be called `users`. You may think it's a small thing, but it's a collection and it doesn't really make sense to have a variable name that implies that it holds a simple entity.

If you really want to make the query work (and again, no need for that since you can simply fetch the organization from the user), the correct naming would have made you realize the comparison you are making doesn't make a lot of sense.  If you had named it `Organization::users`, it would have become pretty clear to you that what you are doing doesn't really make sense:

```
->andWhere('o.users = :user')
```

When seeing this you would probably have realized you are trying to compare a collection to singular entity. Not logical.

For the correct query you would need to make a different comparison, and make sure that the user is *within* the collection of users that belong to the organization. For that you use `MEMBER OF`.

For example, something like this:

```php
public function getOrganizationByUser(User $user): Organization
{
    $organization = $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
        ->andWhere(':user MEMBER OF o.users')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();

    if ($organization instanceof Organization) {
        return $organization;
    }

    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('User without Organization');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. You're absolutely correct.

Answer (score -1):

try this..

```
$this->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('o, u')
    ->from(Organization::class)
    ->join(User::class, 'u')
    ->where('u = :user')
    ->setParameter('user', $this-security->getUser()->getId());// i'm not sure if ->getId() is necessary...
```

or just

```
$this->findBy(['user' => $this-security->getUser()]);
```

Comment: Shoud be `$this->security->getUser()`

Comment: This is wrong. Neither approach would work. Either would result in exactly the same error, and the first one (if worked), would return different results than what the OP expects (an array containing both user and organization, instead of just the organization).